# Identifying the ID of a linked-to tab to attach a click() to get AJAX content

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page with tabs and subtabs, all of which are "filled" by ajax calls initiated when the tab (or subtab) is clicked.

When I hyperlink from content in one tab x subtab combo to another tab x subtab combo, the correct tab x subtab is being selected, but because no click event occurs, no content is loaded.

My plan is to:

1. Get the ID of the linked-to li element
2. Find the a tag inside it and get its ID
3. Use that ID in a .trigger('click') call to initiate the ajax call to load its content (the ID contains the information needed for the backend processing)

I've added a class to the link's a tag and am using the following function.  It fails because 'tst' gives the ID of the current subtab li, not the linked-to one.

```
$('a.totab').live("click",function(){
    var tst = $('li.ui-tabs-selected.pagelink').attr('id');
    var tst2 = $('#'+tst).find('a').attr('id');
    $('#'+tst2).trigger('click');
});
```

'pagelink' is a class that only appears in the subtab li elements. The URL of the link is of the form 'growsafe.asp?id=Z321141S39#techbox=2&sm=4', where techbox=2 is the index of parent tab and sm is the index of the subtab.

I just can't conceptualize my way forward here - suggestions very much appreciated.

Thanks/Bruce

Comment: Note: `live()` is deprecated. Please use `on()` instead, or `delegate()` if `on()` is not yet supported in your version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.totab').live("click",function(){
    var tst = $(this).attr('id');
    var tst2 = $('#'+tst).find('a').attr('id');
    $('#'+tst2).trigger('click');
});
```

Use $(this) for the element clicked. Your javascript is very confusing however, so if you would post the HTML too it might be easier to provide a more optimized solution to your question.